# Instagram Web automation

Tags: python, selenium, web, automation

I want to get the text of the sender in my console.
Here's the current code,

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:1234")#code for the browser

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=opt)#uses the chromedriver
#driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")#opens website

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"_ab8w  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p  _ab9_ _aba8 _abcm").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I keep getting an error that the element was not found, even though I inspected the page and found the class name of the text message (the class name of text messages is "_ab8w  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p  *ab9* _aba8 _abcm"). The text messages don't have an ID either that I could use.

I want this text in the console:
[link to picture of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0iZT.png)

I've tried delaying the program so it waits for the page to load but that did't work.

Comment: What text do you want in console?

Comment: You need to do login for getting the text you want? Because the url you are using is the login page from instagram, in that url there is nothing, and there is a pop up for accepting cookies.

Comment: I just edited the post with a picture

Answer (score 0):

The search by CLASS_NAME needs one class name to find an element. But here you are giving it many class names. Class names in the "class" attribute are separated by spaces. So "_ab8w _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p ab9 _aba8 _abcm" is not a class name but a list of classes separated by spaces.
By.CLASS_NAME will find something if you set `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"_ab8w").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` for example. But I doubt it's a unique class name for that page.
You can find this element using all the list of classes using this locator `(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='_ab8w _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p ab9 _aba8 _abcm']")`. The whole line will look like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='_ab8w _ab94 _ab97 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p ab9 _aba8 _abcm']").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But I'm getting another problem, as you said the class name isn't unique and the text messages in instagram don't have any ID's. Is there another way to locate the text messages?

Comment: All the messages can be found using `messages = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_ab8w  _ab94 _ab96 _ab9f _ab9k _ab9p _abcm"]')`. It returns a list of elements. The contents can be printed by looping through the messages with `for message in messages`. Inside the loop there will be `print(message.text)`. The last message text can be printed using `print(messages[-1].text)`